# Why is fwrite throwing me an Access Violation?

Tags: c++, crash, filesystems, locking, fwrite

I'm recompiling and debugging Yara but for some reason, the Access Violation is thrown when Yara's `yr_rules_save` function tries to execute fwrite of the `hdr` struct into the file.

```
typedef struct _YR_STREAM
{
  void* user_data;

  YR_STREAM_READ_FUNC read;
  YR_STREAM_WRITE_FUNC write;

} YR_STREAM;

typedef size_t (*YR_STREAM_WRITE_FUNC)(
    const void* ptr,
    size_t size,
    size_t count,
    void* user_data);

YR_API int yr_rules_save(
    YR_RULES* rules,
    const char* filename)
{
  int result;

  YR_STREAM stream;
  FILE* fh = fopen(filename, "wb");

  if (fh == NULL)
    return ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN_FILE;

  stream.user_data = fh;
  stream.write = (YR_STREAM_WRITE_FUNC) fwrite; // As write method, uses fwrite

  result = yr_rules_save_stream(rules, &stream); // Here the error

  fclose(fh);
  return result;
}
```

In fact, if we go into `yr_rules_save_stream` in the function being shown, is the line the exception is thrown:

```
  [...]
  if (yr_stream_write(&hdr, sizeof(hdr), 1, stream) != 1)
    return ERROR_WRITING_FILE;
  [...]
```

What is the exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFED05072A6 (ntdll.dll) in ubi-yarac64.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00007FF653018A46.
```

***For details such as the line and the call stack check the screenshot.***

The file is not locked (no software uses it), it does not exists (even if I put "w+b" on fopen) and the pointer to the buffer appears to exists if I check on HxD manually.

**Does anybody have any idea of what is going on here?**

[image: The error shown from Visual Studio]

Comment: If you need to cast a function pointer in order to silence a type error, you're doing something wrong. You must use a function with the correct prototype.

Comment: I don't see any C++ code. Just plain old C.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is, because the fwrite function wrapped by `YR_STREAM_WRITE_FUNC` takes a pointer to a `FILE` type, while in the function `yr_stream_write` it passes a pointer to the `YR_STREAM` struct instead of `YR_STREAM->user_data` (the `FILE` handle previously saved by `yr_rules_save`)

[image: the f. solution]

Comment: So the bug was the cast?

Comment: Strongly recommend You also suggest removing the type cast called out by molbdnilo in the comments under the question as the cast allowed this mistake to be and remain hidden. It will get you again in the future if you change the either function prototype. Also, replace the image of code with code (that's the downvote). The solution description needs to be backed up with code and code as an image is impossible to see by too many users, rendering this answer "Not Useful" to too many SO users.

Comment: No, it was the original code parsing the struct expecting no padding, basically.